why pandas datetime format keep changing?
So, I made GUI using kivymd. It's basically an appointment scheduler app. You just input Name, Phone Number, and Date (it's actually more than this, but if .
I use the DatePicker on kivymd for the Date Part, and I use normal TextField for the name and phone number. I set my program so that when I click the save button, All of my input (name, date, and phone number) would automatically be save on CSV file I already set.
So, on kivymd DatePicker, there's on_ok event. It's the event that would happend if you clicked on the date. Here's how I set my on_ok event, I want so that when I click the date, it would show the date that I pick on the screen, hence why it's self.root.ids.selected_date_label.text = f"{converted_date_string}". And also, origninally, kivymd does not automatically set your choosen date into datetime format. So, hence why I convert it so that it'll be easier when I tried to access the date later.
def on_ok(self, instance_date_picker):
    global converted_date_string
    date = instance_date_picker.get_date()[0]
    date = str(date)
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    converted_date_string =  date_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    self.root.ids.selected_date_label.text = f"{converted_date_string}"
    instance_date_picker.dismiss()

And, I upload all of my input to CSV file :
def upload_data(self):
    name = str(self.root.ids.owner_field.text)
    phone = str(self.root.ids.petname_field.text)

    with open("data_pet_clinic/data_appt.csv", mode='a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([appt, phone, converted_date_string])

And it's successfully save my input to CSV file.
Then, I want to make List Item (using kivymd) of All of the Appointment that has been made. So, in kivymd List Item, there's the HeadlineText and SupportingText. And I want so that the Headline would be the Name and the SupportingText would be the phone number and the date. And I want the list to be sorted base on the date. Here's how I do it :
def extract_data_list(self, csv_file):
    df_appt = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    df_appt['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_appt['Date']).dt.date
    df_appt = df_appt.sort_values(by='Date')

    info = {}
    for i, row in df_appt.iterrows():
        info[i] = row.tolist()

    global headline, display_info
    for info_item, info_value in info.items():
        headline = info_value[0]
        appt_info = [info_value[1], str(info_value[2])]
        display_info = str(appt_info[0]) + " | " + str(appt_info[1])

def list_all(self):
    self.extract_data_list("data_pet_clinic/data_appt.csv")
    self.root.ids.main_scroll.add_widget(
        MDListItem(
            MDListItemHeadlineText(text=str(headline)),
            MDListItemSupportingText(text=str(display_info)),
            pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5},
            radius= [15, 15, 15, 15],
            md_bg_color = get_color_from_hex("#062D3E")
        )
    )

But, then my code gave me an error that say ValueError: time data "13/06/2024" doesn't match format "%m/%d/%Y", at position 4.. It say that it does not match the format.
But then I tried adding format='%d/%m/%Y'), so it would be like this df_appt['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_appt['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date. It works.
What I'm confuse is that, when I tried on a different file, I input the date manually by typing, and I type it as date/month/year format. And it work just fine without adding the `format='%d/%m/%Y'. So, why pandas reading my first file (date is input by kivymd date picker) using month/date/year format? Even though I already save it in the day/month/year format on my CSV file?

@9769953 But when I tried on using different file (I manually input the date as day/month/year) It work just fine without using format='%d/%m/%Y'

Just pass the dayfirst=True parameter

@mozway Okay, but is pandas datetime format always inconsistent and you always have to set it first? Or is there something wrong with my code?
